# Include search bar in page cms

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, blocks

I want to add the search bar in my 404 cms page. So I've written in the content of it :

```
{{block type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Search::form.mini.phtml"}}
```

But it doesn't shows anything. I've showed the templates hints and I I know that the location of the search bar template is in this location :

> vendor/magento/module-search/view/frontend/templates/form.mini.phtml

So I don't know why my solution doesn't work. Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

change `type` to `class`

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Search::form.mini.phtml"}}
```

Comment: i need to include search in my custom module template file. how that can be done?

Comment: @jafarpinjar https://blog.qaisarsatti.com/magento_2/magento-2-call-phtml-file-phtml-file-cms-page/

Comment: hi @Qaisar, I have added template file in my custom module, search bar is working if added in cms, but i need to load search bar in same template file of my module. how it can be added

Comment: @jafarpinjar open link and read there is solution to call it directly in phtml file.

Comment: hi @Qaisar, my question is different, i am not including my template in other phtml, i am looking for code how to include default search bar form in my custom module template file

Comment: @jafarpinjar you want it to add through layout file?

Comment: hi @Qaisar, from layout or directly in phtml file

Comment: @jafarpinjar . `<?php 
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template")->setTemplate("Magento_Search::form.mini.phtml")->toHtml();
?>` use code directly in phtmlfile